# How do I get rid of the extra slash at the end of the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I have this [link](http://posnation.com/restaurant_pos/) and as you can see there is an extra / at the end. Basically i have a restaurant_pos folder with an index.php file in it but apache is adding the extra slash. I thought there was a way to do this in htaccess with directory directives off or something like that...not sure the name...any ideas

Comment: from a functional point of view it makes no difference.

Comment: Are you talking about `DirectorySlash Off` directive?

Comment: yes but for an SEO purpose it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you (redirect if UR has trailing slash):

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# get rid of trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

But you may have that extra slash added by some other rule in your .htaccess. If above will not help and you have some rewrite rules already in place -- please post them in your question.

Comment: i added DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# get rid of trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L] to the .htaccess file in the main directory and one in the restaurant_pos directory and nothing

Comment: @Tamer And .. what happened? URL Should have changed in browser's address bar. 1) Please confirm that you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled. 2) If you can edit Apache's config files (httpd.conf, httpd-vhost.conf) then enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log.

Comment: i get Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /restaurant_pos on this server.

Comment: @Tamer This means it is working :)  Please remove either `DirectorySlash Off` or `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]` line and try again -- preferably on another browser, as 301 redirects are usually cached by modern browser (unless you clear caches and restart it)

Comment: its actually not working...go here http://posnation.com/cafeteria-pos and you will get a permission issue... and in my /cafeteria-pos folder i have DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Comment: @Tamer So without these rules you have double slash at the end, with this rule you now have no slashes at all... It is definitely some screw up in configuration. What I think it _may be_ -- with current content you have disabled rewrite rules from parent .htaccess. If my assumption is correct (since you have not provided your existing htaccess files) .. then I suggest 1) remove `DirectorySlash Off` line (so you only have `RewriteEngine On  RewriteBase /`) or 2) Add `RewriteOptions inherit`. If still nothing -- then I see no reason for me to guess any further - provide your .htacecss files.

Comment: you got it ...give me one sec

Comment: this is the main .htaccess file http://pastie.org/2233677 and the one in the cafeteria-pos folder is here http://pastie.org/2233684

Comment: @Tamer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1595/discussion-between-lazyone-and-tamer)